# mysqli one date between 2 column dates

Tags: date, mysqli, between

I'm trying to get the number of rows from database, maybe like:

```php
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE '2015-03-01' IS BETWEEN column_1 and column_2  ");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1) {
    echo "nothing found !";
} else {
    echo "numrow found !";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read manual [mysql between syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

IS between is wrong syntax:

The BETWEEN operator selects values within a range. The values can be numbers, text, or dates.

```
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE '2015-03-01' BETWEEN column_1 and column_2");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1) {
            echo "nothing found !";
    }else{
     echo "numrow found !";
    }
```